# How to populate vuejs data variable with json from function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a project that uses jQuery, and I have a lot of functions that return json, and I am trying to populate a data variable with some test data but when I loop through the data I am getting nothing.

I have checked to make sure that my ajax call is returning the json data and it is,  and I am kind of at a loss on why nothing is being returned

```
<div id="app">
   <template v-for="person in persons">
       <div>
           {{ person.FirstName }}
       </div>
   </template>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        created: function () {
            this.GetUserDetails();
        },
        data: {
            persons: []
        },
        methods: {
            GetUserDetails() {
                this.persons = CommonFunctions.GetJSON("Person");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is some of the Person json,

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Auroora",
    "LastName": "Kosel",
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "FirstName": "Nevins",
    "LastName": "Rulf",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "FirstName": "Silvana",
    "LastName": "Cragoe",
    "gender": "Female"
 }]
```

** EDIT **
Here is the GetJSON function

```
var CommonFunctions = {
    GetJSON: (whichOne) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Scripts/" + whichOne + "JSON.json",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `console.log(this.persons)` in `GetUserDetails`, do you get proper value?

Comment: comes back as undefined

Comment: Can you include code of `CommonFunctions.GetJSON` function?

Comment: Just made an edit and added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetJSON()` function doesn't return anything.

```
var CommonFunctions = {
    GetJSON(whichOne)  {
      return $.getJSON("../Scripts/" + whichOne + "JSON.json");
//    ^^^^^^
    }
}

Now it returns the request/promise (and uses jQuery's shorthand method for retrieving json).
```

In your component you'd write

```
async GetUserDetails() {
  this.persons = await CommonFunctions.GetJSON("Person");
}
```

Or if you don't like async/await:

```
 CommonFunctions.GetJSON("Person").then(data => {
   this.persons = data;
 });
```

Comment: If I add a console.log(data) into the success of the GetJSON it returns the data

Comment: Weird, place a `console.log(this.persons)` below the `this.persons = CommonFunctions.GetJSON("Person");` line, what does it log?

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: Exactly, because the GetJSON doesn't return anything/undefined. I'll update my answer with working GetJSON method...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a GetJSON implementation that returns the request/promise.

Comment: Ah ok, so from reading both answers it looks like the issue was a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding, ajax function is asynchronous, so it doesn't return directly

There is a simple workaround:

```
   methods: {
        GetUserDetails() {
            this.persons = CommonFunctions.GetJSON("Person", this);
        }
    }
```

and in helper function:

```
var CommonFunctions = {
    GetJSON: (whichOne, self) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Scripts/" + whichOne + "JSON.json",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                self.persons = data
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```